# Print pdf in webpage

Tags: asp.net, html, pdf, adobe-reader

I have an ASP.net web page embeded a pdf file using the object tag as below:

```
    <object data="<%=this.FilePath %>" type="application/pdf" style="width:600px; height:820px; border:solid 1px #888;">
    <embed src="<%=this.FilePath %>" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
```

The viewer run good and I assume all client PCs have Adobe Reader installed.
I want to make a button to simply:

1. remove the button panel of adobe reader
2. create a button to print the pdf document(using the reader's API or any other method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That type of customization isn't possible in the Acrobat Reader Plugin AFAIK.

You can hide the default button panel by adding `#toolbar=0` to the url, but the user can just 'unhide' it if he wants.

Comment: Hi Stephen, do you means it is not possible to use javascript or something to just activate the print action of Acrobat Reader?

Comment: No, that is not possible.